# No plugin found for prefix 'azure-function' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Tags: azure-functions, maven-plugin, spring-cloud-function

I have been trying to run a spring-cloud-azure-function on my local machine. But it looks like I am having a hard time in figuring out the pom plugins. I have tried from the Microsoft Doc of how to create an azure function with spring cloud functions. Here is the reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/getting-started-with-spring-cloud-function-in-azure

Here is the detailed pom.xml I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-azure-function</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Helloworld Spring Function on Azure</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <azure.functions.java.library.version>2.0.0</azure.functions.java.library.version>
        <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.17.0</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
        <functionResourceGroup>sample-resource-group</functionResourceGroup>
        <functionAppName>my-azure-function</functionAppName>
        <functionAppRegion>westeurope</functionAppRegion>
        <stagingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}</stagingDirectory>
        <start-class>com.demo.HelloworldApplication</start-class>
        <spring.boot.wrapper.version>1.0.26.RELEASE</spring.boot.wrapper.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0.RC1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.functions.java.library.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <resourceGroup>${functionResourceGroup}</resourceGroup>
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <region>${functionAppRegion}</region>
                    <runtime>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <javaVersion>11</javaVersion>
                    </runtime>
                    <appSettings>
                        <!-- Run Azure Function from package file by default -->
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>~4</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME</name>
                            <value>java</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/azure
                                    </directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--Remove obj folder generated by .NET SDK in maven clean-->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>obj</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Here is the exception I am getting

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'azure-function' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, o
rg.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\snp17\.m2\repository), spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot), spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/
milestone), spring-releases (https://repo.spring.io/libs-release-local), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix (MojoDescriptorCreator.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor (MojoDescriptorCreator.java:220)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:577)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: Have you tried one of the working samples - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/main/spring-cloud-function-samples

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but it was my command, which was the problem. Instead of 'mvn azure-functions:run' I tried with 'mvn:azure-function:run'. So yes, there was a missing 's'.

Answer (score 3):

Glad @[SatyaPanigrahy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7544358/satya-panigrahy) that you resolved the issue yourself. Posting the resolution as an answer to help other community members!

There is a typo in the command when running which the OP used `mvn:azure-function:run` where the letter `s` is missed in the `azure-functions`. The correct command is `mvn azure-functions:run`.

This command is used to run the Azure Functions runtime host.

Please find the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-java?tabs=bash,azure-cli,browser#run-the-function-locally) given about running the Java Azure Function using `mvn` commands given by Microsoft.